# Conditional Statement in SQL defining variables

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT c.review, u.username, c.date, c.good, c.rate_id, r.rating
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN users AS u
    ON c.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN items as i
    ON i.items_id = c.item_id
LEFT JOIN master_cat AS m
    ON m.cat_id = i.cat_id
LEFT JOIN ratings as r
    ON r.item_id = c.item_id 
WHERE i.item = '{$item}' AND c.user_id = r.user_id
ORDER by {$sort};
```

But this is limiting.  Because if that WHERE statement (`c.user_id = r.user_id`) matches, I JSON print out `c.rating`.  If not, where it prints out in my application and it will skip data that I need.

For example, if it matches a comment to a rating from the same user, it will pair the data.  But some comments *don't* have ratings (you can rate from 1 - 5) associated with them yet.  So, instead of *skipping* the data with a inflexible WHERE clause, I want to make it conditional and print out 0 where later on I can say `IF 0, print out "not rated"`. (this will not be done in SQL but JAVA. In SQL, I just need to store 0 in the `MySQL` DB.)

I am assuming I will need to drop the `WHERE` and make part of the `SELECT`?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN ratings as r
    ON r.item_id = c.item_id AND c.user_id = r.user_id
WHERE i.item = '{$item}'
```

That condition when placed in the `where` clause transforms the `left join` into an `inner join`

Comment: Beautiful.  That is it.  `null` works just as well.  Marking correct.